# Chrome version breaks input focus with gtag

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, tags, focus, google-tag-manager

I have a very strange behavior when working with google tag.
And this error only  occurs in 1 specified Chrome version.

Testing environment:

- Chrome: 116.0.5845.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Reactjs version: 17.0.1
- Gatsby 4.6.0

Scenarios:

- We want to track all conversion tags from user signup till user login.....
- Assume we have a trackTag function to report conversion tags to google tag manager(GTM)
- Whenever a click event occurs, we will call trackTag.
- But, a very strange iframe has been appended every click or by every timeout seconds... (I dont know this)
- We checked and found that the iframe name is "join-ad-interest-group"

Screenshot:
[image]

Note:

- This bug only in specific chrome version.

Our input controls not log focus.

Answer (score 0):

Doubleclick is Google's adserver. Searching for "doubleclick" in conjuction with the "join-ad-interest-group" data attribute leads to this page about a test for Google Ad Manager: https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/12052605?hl=en.

Since the test uses a browser API, it makes some sense that it only shows up in certain builds.